# Require A Specific Answer On A DropDown (jQuery Validator)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working with a bootstrap multiform, and using the jQuery validator, its been very easy to use, and has great documentation, but I can't figure out one problem.   I want to require a specific answer for the field to be valid in a select, dropdown.  E.G:  If I have Yes, No, And Maybe as options, I want to require the user to Choose Yes for there not to be an error.  I've inlcuded some of my code below, thank you.

```
<div class="myclass">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="sel3">question1</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="Has1">
      <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Select Answer</option> 
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option> 

    </select> 
    <br> 
    <label for="sel5">question 2</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel5" name="Has2">
     <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Select Year</option> 
     <option>2012</option> 
     <option>2013</option> 
     <option>2014</option> 
     <option>2015</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div> 

 $('.myform').validate({ // initialize plugin
   // ignore:":not(:visible)",      
   rules: {
    Surgery_Year: {  

      required: true, 
      number: true,

    }, 

    Has_Surgery: { 
      required: true,
      number: false,
      //something to make Yes The only valid option.
    },
```

Comment: You could have numbers for the values and use equals, not equals or greater than etc. Rather than using string values

Comment: This is what I would up doing.